# VB.Net LINQ link two datatables and show all columns

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a little issue here with a LINQ sentence. Basically I try to JOIN two datatables with LINQ, but I don't want specify the columns that will shows me in the result.

I want all columns in the result without specify them in LINQ.
Or some method to select the columns dynamically?

Any idea?

Code:

```
Dim vDT1 As New DataTable
    vDT1.Columns.Add("Key")
    vDT1.Columns.Add("Data1")
    vDT1.Columns.Add("Data2")

    vDT1.Rows.Add({"01", "DATA1_AAAA", "DATA2_AAAA"})
    vDT1.Rows.Add({"02", "DATA1_BBBB", "DATA2_BBBB"})
    vDT1.Rows.Add({"03", "DATA1_CCCC", "DATA2_CCCC"})
    vDT1.Rows.Add({"04", "DATA1_DDDD", "DATA2_DDDD"})

    Dim vDT2 As New DataTable
    vDT2.Columns.Add("Key")
    vDT2.Columns.Add("Data3")
    vDT2.Columns.Add("Data4")

    vDT2.Rows.Add({"01", "DATA3_AAAA", "DATA4_AAAA"})
    vDT2.Rows.Add({"02", "DATA3_BBBB", "DATA4_BBBB"})
    vDT2.Rows.Add({"03", "DATA3_CCCC", "DATA4_CCCC"})
    vDT2.Rows.Add({"04", "DATA3_DDDD", "DATA4_DDDD"})

    Dim vLINQ = From DT1 In vDT1.AsEnumerable
                        Join DT2 In vDT2.AsEnumerable
                        On DT1.Field(Of String)("Key") Equals DT2.Field(Of String)("Key")
                        Select Key = DT1.Field(Of String)("Key"), Data1 = DT1.Field(Of String)("Data1"), Data2 = DT1.Field(Of String)("Data2"),
                            Data3 = DT2.Field(Of String)("Data3"), Data4 = DT2.Field(Of String)("Data4")
```

*** I want skip the "SELECT" in LINQ

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the LINQ dynamic sentence instant in order to achieve this requirement.

[LINQ dynamic](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have linq construct without `select`. You should either have `select` or `group by` clause in linq query.

```
Dim vLINQ = (From DT1 In vDT1.AsEnumerable
            Join DT2 In vDT2.AsEnumerable
            On DT1.Field(Of String)("Key") Equals DT2.Field(Of String)("Key")
            Select new with
            {
               .Key = DT1.Field(Of String)("Key"), 
               .Data1 = DT1.Field(Of String)("Data1"), 
               .Data2 = DT1.Field(Of String)("Data2"),
               .Data3 = DT2.Field(Of String)("Data3"), 
               .Data4 = DT2.Field(Of String)("Data4")
            }).ToList()
```

Now vLINQ is a List(of annonymousType) which has key, Data1..Data4 as properties and can be used as

```
//sorry for C# code
foreach(var l in vLinq)
{
   console.writeline(l.Key);
   console.writeline(l.Data1);
}
```

Comment: mmmm, OK, do you know any method to create dynamically the fields that I want display?

Comment: Thanks by the fast response. But I'm thinking in something more dynamically. For example: I want create a method that can by apply by any datatables to any combination of columns. Then, I need create these List(Of AnnonymousType) since the structures of the DataTables.